# How to pass input text value to input range using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this example, I can change the range input, the number will be changed in the field.
I want to enter a number and have the range change the same way.

https://snipp.ru/jquery/jquery-ui-slider#

I tried to put the values the other way around, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please include the example as formatted text, not as a link to an external resource. Also describe the desired behaviour more clearly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just track the `input field value change event` [Working example](https://codepen.io/saaidur/pen/dyqGjao)

Comment: Thank you! And how to make it so that when the value changes, the slider immediately moves by clicking somewhere nearby?

Comment: use keyup instead of change. here it is https://codepen.io/saaidur/pen/dyqGjao

Answer (score 0):

While creating a slider you can pass a value inside the options object.

After creation, you can manipulate the value of the slider like this:

`mySlider.slider('value', 42)`

note that "mySlider" is a jQuery object, not just the DOM element